# How to abort saveui pipeline in Sitecore and then reset values?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I am trying to implement a saveui pipeline processor in Sitecore 6.  Basically I have created a custom processor that presents the user with a popup message depending on which fields they may have changed on the item and what the new data is.  If they made certain changes then they are presented with a popup asking them if they want to continue.  If they answer no then the pipeline is aborted.  That is all working.  However I noticed that when you abort the pipeline all Sitecore seems to do is not save.  All of the changes that the user made to the content item are still there in the UI.  If you navigate away from the item in Sitecore, it will prompt you if you want to save the changes.  Is there some way that I can get the Sitecore UI to cancel all of the changes and revert all of the fields back to their initial values?  Aborting the pipeline is good because I don't want to save, but I also want to cancel the save in the UI too.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Sample Code:

```
public class CustomSaveProcessor
{
  public void Process(SaveArgs args)
  {
    Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, "args");
    if(args.Items == null)
    { return; }

    if(args.IsPostback)
    {
      if(args.Parameters["runContext"] == "firstQuestion")
      {
        if((args.Result == null) || (args.Result == "null") || (args.Result == "no") || (args.Result == "cancel"))
        {
          args.AbortPipeline();
          //Should there be something here to tell the Sitecore UI to reset the values?
          return;
        }
        else
        {
          //User has answered first question Yes
          //This means they want to save the changes to the item
          //We also want to ask a second question that effects other content items

          SheerResponse.YesNoCancel("Do you want to also modify other items?", "300px", "200px");
          args.Parameters["runContext"] = "secondQuestion";
          args.WaitForPostBack();
        }
      }
      else
      {
        if(args.Result == "yes")
        {
          //This is the answer to second question
          //Custom code here to modify other content items
        }
        //We are completely done now.
        return;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      //Ask the user the first question
      SheerResponse.YesNoCancel("Are you sure you want to proceed?", "300px", "200px");
      args.Parameters["runContext"] = "firstQuestion";
      args.WaitForPostback();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just reload the content tree with the following code.

```
String refresh = String.Format("item:refreshchildren(id={0})", Sitecore.Context.Item.Parent.ID);
Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.SendMessage(this, refresh);
```

Or as Corey discovered if you want to refersh the item you'd use

```
String refresh = String.Format("item:load(id={0})", myOriginalItem.ID);
Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.SendMessage(this, refresh);
```

See this [post](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2011/08/Load-or-Reload-an-Item-in-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx) for more details

Comment: Where would I put that code?  Would it go in my custom SaveUI processor?  I tried adding it after the args.AbortPipeline() line but that had no effect.  It didn't do anything.  Also, won't refreshing the content item still give me the Sitecore warning message asking me if I want to save the changes first?

Comment: Yes it should go there, you may not get the prompt for a call in code or you might be able to handle it. Worth a try.

Comment: Yeah I tried that but it didn't work.  It didn't really seem to do anything actually.

Comment: Does the Sitecore.Context etc item return a guid for you? The code seems fine, I've had a look at the NewsMover Module which reloads the content tree after sorting items.

Comment: Ok.  I found that Sitecore.Context.Item was referring to an item in the Core database (probably since I was running this code from a saveui processor).  I fixed that and I was able to change it so that it was now referring to the parent of the content item in question.  What I can tell from the code is that it is telling Sitecore to refresh the content tree and to refresh the children of the item's parent.  Well, it does that.  It refreshes the content tree on the left.  But it has no effect at all on the Content Editor on the right.  I want to refresh the Content Editor form on the right.

Comment: I figured it out!  I had to re-load the item instead of just refreshing the content tree.  The refresh string needed to look like this: String refresh = String.Format("item:load(id={0})", myOriginalItem.ID);  Should I edit your response to include this?  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to reload the current content item after aborting your custom save handler to set the intial values of the content item. Not sure if you then still get the "alert message".

Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362464/refresh-sitecore-after-changing-icon-of-item) with a similiar issue